# how to list the variables defined by a Bash function, including those pre-existing variables that are unchanged in value by the function

Tags: bash, list, function, variables

I want to run a Bash function that defines a few variables and then, after the function has run, list all of the variables that it has 'attempted' to define. Such a list would include the names of those variables that were pre-existing but were unchanged in value by the function. Could you point me in the right direction on this?

EDIT: I have added some code below both to explain further what it is that I want to accomplish and to offer inspiration.

```
#!/bin/bash

variable1="zappo"

#listOfVariables1="$(printenv)"
listOfVariables1="$(set)"

function1(){
    variable1="zappo"
}

function1

#listOfVariables2="$(printenv)"
listOfVariables2="$(set)"

echo -e "\ncomparing initial list of variables with final list of variables...\n"
diff <(echo "${listOfVariables1}") <(echo "${listOfVariables2}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `set` command will display all shell environmental variables, including those user defined.

To easily the variable list (which can be quite long) before and after a function, you could use `diff`
e.g.

```
set > set_before.tmp
my_func
set > set_after.tmp    
diff set_before.tmp set_after.tmp
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I have added some code above to try to use ```set``` as you suggest. I am not sure how to proceed in order to acquire a list that includes ```variable1``` at the end of the script.

Comment: Why do you require `variable1` at the *end* of the script? That is not mentioned in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

try to edit you bash function it to print environment in the end of execution. Then you can compare (`diff list1 list2`) list you got with `printenv` results without your script.

```
#!/bin/bash
printenv > /tmp/list1

{
    cat $(which your_function)
    echo 'printenv > /tmp/list2'
} >/tmp/fake.sh

chmod +x /tmp/fake.sh
/tmp/fake.sh

diff /tmp/list1 /tmp/list2
```

also, if you need just to set this variables, you need to run `. $(which your_function)`

variables will not be changed in parent scope if you simple run `your_function`.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I have added some code above to try to use ```printenv``` as you suggest. I am not sure how to proceed in order to acquire a list that includes ```variable1``` at the end of the script.

Comment: just try to use code in my answer. Replace `your_function` with function you want and run.